# Thymeleaf cannot render bullet symbol

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue trying to display the bullet symbol on my template with Thymeleaf. Instead of the bullet symbol appearing, a ? is shown in its place.

I've tried:

- Using HTML codes such as `&#8226; &#x2022; &bull;`
- Using Unicode
- Having Java create the symbol and adding it to the template
- Using `th:text` and `th:utext`

All my attempts failed. There has to be a way to have Thymeleaf render it

```
<h2 class="dates" th:utext="${month} + ' ' + ${dateOne} + ' ' + ${dateTwo} + ${bullet} + ${dateThree} + ', ' + ${year}"></h2>
```

Comment: `+ '&bull;' +` works for me

Comment: If you place `&bull;` *outside* of your `h2` element, in regular markup, does it render correctly?